# Check values of the keys in dictionary and construct matrix for keys only using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary as mentioned below.

```
mydictionary = {colours: [red, pink, blue, green, yellow], animals: [cat, rat, dog, goat], 
vehicles: [car, jeep, van, bus, lorry]}
```

I also have a matrix for each value of the keys as given in the examples below (if that value is in the essay I read I make it 1, otherwise 0).

```
        red, pink, blue, green, yellow, cat, rat, ... bus, lorry
Essay1:  1     0     0    1       1      0    0        1     0
Essay2:  0     1     0    0       1      0    1        0     0
```

Hence, this looks like a list of lists.

```
[[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]]
```

Now by using 'mydictionary' I want to transform the above matrix as follows (That is, if one or more values of the key is 1, I mark the key as 1, else 0).

```
      Colours, Animals, Vehicles
Essay1: 1         0        1
Essay2: 1         1        0
```

The above mentioned matrix can be written as a list of lists as below.

```
[[1,0,1], [1,1,0]]
```

I am new to pandas, Hence, I am interested in knowing if this is possible to do using pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap `keys` with `values` to new `dict`, rename `df` columns and then `groupby` by columns names with aggregate `max`:

```
L = [[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]]
cols = ['red', 'pink', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'cat', 'rat', 'bus', 'lorry']
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=cols)
print (df)
   red  pink  blue  green  yellow  cat  rat  bus  lorry
0    1     0     0      1       1    0    0    1      0
1    0     1     0      0       1    0    1    0      0

d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in mydictionary.items() for k in oldv}
df = df.rename(columns=d).groupby(axis=1, level=0).max()
print (df)
         animals  colours  vehicles
Essay1:        0        1         1
Essay2:        1        1         0
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how you input my initial matrix to obtain the final matrix?

Comment: I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if data are in file like `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')` (change separator if necessary)

Comment: Instead of using a csv file, can I just use it as df as list of lists?
 [[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]]. I tried your code and I get an error saying 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: I think yes, see edited answer. only is necessary add columns names

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {v: k for k, l in mydictionary.items() for v in l}
df.groupby(df.columns.map(m.get), 1).sum().clip(0, 1)

        animals  colours  vehicles
Essay1        0        1         1
Essay2        1        1         0
```